# How can I calculate the buoyant force on an object without knowing in advance the amount of water displaced?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, statics, naval-engineering

Suppose I know the mass and volume of an object, as well as its exact shape and density distribution as a function of space (x,y,z).  Without submerging it to determine the amount of water displaced, how can I determine the buoyant force?  Is there a way to determine the amount of displaced water based on knowing the density of the object as well as its shape?

Ultimately, I'd like to use this information to predict whether a particular design I have made will sink or float, but I need to know the buoyant force in order to do this.  How can I predict this force a priori without experimentation?

Comment: Well, if you say you know the volume...

Comment: @SolarMike: the volume of the object itself, not the volume of the water displaced by the object...

Comment: So what do you think the immersed volume is then?

Comment: Or, to put it another way - what is the max immersed volume and will that volume of displaced water weigh more than the object?

Comment: To be clear, can this object's average density be lower than water's? That is, can it float? Because if it can't, then there's obviously no difference between the object's volume and its displaced volume since the whole thing will sink.

Comment: @Wasabi: An object more dense than water (e.g. iron) can still float if it is shaped in a suitable way.  When you say "averaged", are you referring to the enclosed volume within the object or the volume of the material comprising the object itself?

Comment: @Paul: Indeed I wasn't clear. I did mean the enclosed volume.

Comment: @SolarMike: For clarification, when I refer to volume of the object, i'm referring to the volume of the material comprising the object, not including any void spaces enclosed within its hull. To answer your question, in the worse case scenario when the object sinks, the maximum volume of displaced water is equal to the volume of the enclosed object and the weight of the water displaced would be less than the weight of the object itself.  But how do I determine the weight of displaced water a priori without knowing how much water is displaced in the case where it floats?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail to the shape? Is it hollow? Does buoyant stability matter? Does it have some sort of symmetry?

Comment: @Andrew: Stability is another issue altogether which I will address in my design at a later time.  Yes, the shape is hollow and (ideally) symmetric.  But I'm looking for a general method to calculate the buoyancy force based on the object's geometry and density distribution.

Comment: @Paul, in the case where it floats the weight of the displaced water balances through a natural dynamic process to be equal to the weight of your object.  Let's say that it floats but you step on it and release your foot... then the displaced water is greater than the weight, there's an imbalance in the force, F = M A, and the object rises until the forces are balanced again.

Comment: If it floats the weight of the water is the weight of the object.

Answer (score 3):

Don't refer to the volume as the volume of material.  Use volume as the outer dimensions of the object.

The volume of the water will be equal to the mass of the object (it if floats).  Just divide the mass of the object by the density of water for displaced water.  That will also be the exact volume of your object that is below the water line.

It does not matter to the water if the object is hollow or not.  If the mass / volume of the object is greater than that of water it will sink.

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy)

> with the clarifications that for a sunken object the volume of
>   displaced fluid is the volume of the object, and for a floating object
>   on a liquid, the weight of the displaced liquid is the weight of the
>   object

Comment: So, the effective volume of the object (not just the volume of material) is used to compute the  density of the object), and if it is less than the density of water, it floats?  Also, what about the buoyant force?  Is it always equal to the weight of the object regardless of whether or not it floats?

Comment: @Paul, if an object floats the force of buoyancy is its weight obviously. If it sinks the force of buoyancy is its volume in liters multiplied by kilograms. Just in case of boats and ships the force changes drastically if they sink, the volume will then be the volume of material, not the voolume of the vessel, which will be a much diminished buoyancy.

Comment: @Paul I feel like I answered the question.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The buoyancy is equal to weight of water of displaced volume of the object.

If it's heavier than water it will sink and as long as you know the volume you know the buoyancy!

But if the object is not heavier than water, it will float.  A part of the object will submerge, displacing (in the static case) exactly enough water to equalize the water's buoyant force with the object's weight.  The level of water at which this occurs is named the *draft line.*

We need to find the object's CG, and its center of geometry.

$$ CG = (\sum \Delta v.\rho_v)/v $$ and center of geometry is a analytical process depending on its shape or combination of shapes and surfaces.

The axis of float is vertical from CG to center of geometry and draft volume is such that $$\Sigma \Delta v.\rho\space \text{submerged volume of water} = \text{weight of object}$$
  ** Edit**

The submerged volume is a given and is equall to the weight of the object. However to calculate the draft line one needs to compile the geometey  of the object as a function of the vertical axis say Z.

Then by equating the volume integral of  submerged volume by the weight we get the Z of draft-line. Z is the upper limit of integration.

This process for many nicely behaving volumes is rather easy for instance for a submerged cone the volume is $$ V=2/3 Z. \pi .sin(theta)^2$$ and $\theta$ is half the cone angle.

$$Z = 2/3 . \pi.sin(\theta)^2/V  $$

Comment: So don't you have two unknowns there...

Comment: @SolarMike, What do you mean two unkown variables.

Comment: The vol submerged and vol of water... ie exactly that which the OP wants to find out...

Comment: @Solar Mike, I have modified my answer to address your question. This is the subject of Naval and Marine engineering. Not only the object can be non- homogeneous, but the liquid too can be stratified.

Comment: @kamran Then density of water only changes 0.01% in 2000 meters of depth.

Comment: @paparazzo, I routinely use my cell-phone app and so I get many unintended auto correction errors. The buoyancy of an object as you rightly mention is just the volume of displaced water not multiplied by density of water. Also the volume of a cone is 1/3 of comparable cylinder not 2/3. In good time I clean my post on a computer. My apologies for now.